# Creating a "Virtual" Display to monitor multiple different displays

Tags: nvidia, display, desktop-environments

I'm working on an installation project that requires me to display visuals across 3 x screens which I am managing via Nvidia X-screen in XCFE (I am running an Nvidia RTX 3090 with 4 display ports).

Is there any way to set up a 'virtual' display whereby via a fourth display, I could monitor the output of the other three? Would this even be possible?

Comment: Please start with OS/release details.